# Creating JSON object using json.dumps

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to convert a Python dictionary to JSON format to post to an API using requests.post(). I believe it is not working as the output from json.dumps is always enclosed in quotes, so if I use POST method in Postman it returns: {
  "message": "Unable to decode data"
}

In the Python docs for json.dumps it has this example:

```
>>>import json
>>>print(json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
{"4": 5, "6": 7}
```

However when I try this in the console I get the same output enclosed in quotes and when I use the type() function on it it says that is a string, not a JSON object which I am looking for.

How can I achieve my aim? Apologies if this seems like a repeat question, but all the answers I have read mention using json.dumps() which I thought was meant to return a JSON object not a string.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON always is a string. That's the whole point of it - it's an export format for the purpose of storing objects in a string, so what you see is 100% correct. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: OK thanks. Basically all I want is to have dictionary with double quotes instead of single quotes and then it will work for as my payload in requests.post()

Comment: There is no such thing as a "dictionary with double quotes". :) A dictionary is a data structure, it does not have any quotes. Quotes are *one* way to represent that data structure when you need to print it out, like on the Python console. Python's `print()` function decides to represent (i.e. "serialize to string") the data structure using single quotes. The same data structure when serialized with JSON is represented with double quotes. They both are string representations of the same thing.

Comment: So what you have is a string in JSON format (trust me, `json.dumps()` does that correctly) and what you want is to send that to a server using `requests.post()`. Maybe you forgot to inform the server of that data format you are using? You need to set the `Content-Type` request header to tell the server that the data it is about to receive is JSON, as opposed to the many other things it could be.

Comment: Sorry, it turns out the single/doubles quote does not matter - i tested with both and it works fine. Think it must be something with the data structure I am trying to send. At least I learnt something...thanks!

Comment: The single quotes/double quotes thing *does* matter. The string `{'4': 5, '6': 7}` is not JSON, but the string `{"4": 5, "6": 7}` is. The first form will not be accepted by the server no matter what you do. The second form will be accepted when it a) is declared properly in the request headers and b) represents a data structure that matches the server's expectations.